# More than 10 lines in a node.js stack error?

Tags: node.js, stack-trace

Is there a way to get more than 10 lines in a node.js stack error?

```
function a() { dieInHell(); }
function b() { a(); }
function c() { b(); }
function d() { c(); }
function e() { d(); }
function f() { e(); }
function g() { f(); }
function h() { g(); }
function i() { h(); }
function j() { i(); }
function k() { j(); }
function l() { k(); }
function m() { l(); }
function n() { m(); }
function o() { n(); }
function p() { o(); }
function q() { p(); }

try {
    q();
}
catch(e) {
    console.log(e.stack);
}
```

shows :

```
$ node debug.js 
ReferenceError: dieInHell is not defined
    at a (/Users/julien/tmp/debug.js:2:5)
    at b (/Users/julien/tmp/debug.js:6:5)
    at c (/Users/julien/tmp/debug.js:10:5)
    at d (/Users/julien/tmp/debug.js:14:5)
    at e (/Users/julien/tmp/debug.js:18:5)
    at f (/Users/julien/tmp/debug.js:22:5)
    at g (/Users/julien/tmp/debug.js:26:5)
    at h (/Users/julien/tmp/debug.js:30:5)
    at i (/Users/julien/tmp/debug.js:34:5)
    at j (/Users/julien/tmp/debug.js:38:5)
```

Is there a way to get more than 10 calls?

Comment: Better debugging is a priority for the future versions of Node.JS

Comment: Do i take from your comment that this can't be done yet?

Comment: Nope. But better debugging is on the list for .6 :)

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Easiest solution for that is to start your code with following:

```
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;
```

If you'd like to see stack trace that spans over setTimeout/setInterval calls, then more sophisticated https://github.com/mattinsler/longjohn would be the way to go.

Comment: Error.stackTraceLimit didn't do it for me when I last tried.

Comment: Note that some packages might [change](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v3.8.1/bin/webpack.js#L331) `stackTraceLimit`. Also, it affects only what you get in `Error.stack` from what I can see. Built-in debugger always displays full stack (`bt` command).

Comment: And apparently, stack trace doesn't follow async operations. In other words, in a callback of an asynchronous call your stack starts from scratch (it's basically empty).

Comment: @x-yuri Node.js team is working on that ( https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11865 ) Otherwise full stack is visible in Chrome debugger when you run Node applicaiton with `--inspect` or `--inpect-brk` command

Comment: Omg this was driving me crazy.  Thanks for this info!

Comment: I like about JS that you can use **Infinity** as a number.

Answer (score 91):

You can pass stack trace limit as a command line param to `node`:

`node --stack-trace-limit=1000 debug.js` // default 10

BTW, another thing which sounds unlikely to happen, but just wasted a few hours of my time for debugging, is **the stack size (which defaults to 492 kB)**. You can have very uninformative errors if the stack is exhausted (`RangeError` without any additional info). **You can increase the stack size with**:

`node --stack-size=1024 debug.js` // default 492

In the world of callback-to-callback-to-callback chainings, it's in fact very easy to exceed the stack size for big input sizes, if the program is not written in this in mind.

To see all stack-related options:

`node --v8-options | grep -B0 -A1 stack`

Comment: --stack-trace-limit still working as of 0.10.22, thanks!

Comment: As of Node.js v8.0.0, you can also set this in the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable, e.g. `NODE_OPTIONS='--stack-trace-limit=10000' /path/to/some-script`. Useful if you're not invoking `node` directly.

Answer (score 13):

You can set the trace limit within `NODE_OPTIONS` variable:

```
$ NODE_OPTIONS=--stack-trace-limit=100 node debug.js
ReferenceError: dieInHell is not defined
    at a (/tmp/debug.js:1:16)
    at b (/tmp/debug.js:2:16)
    at c (/tmp/debug.js:3:16)
    at d (/tmp/debug.js:4:16)
    at e (/tmp/debug.js:5:16)
    at f (/tmp/debug.js:6:16)
    at g (/tmp/debug.js:7:16)
    at h (/tmp/debug.js:8:16)
    at i (/tmp/debug.js:9:16)
    at j (/tmp/debug.js:10:16)
    at k (/tmp/debug.js:11:16)
    at l (/tmp/debug.js:12:16)
    at m (/tmp/debug.js:13:16)
    at n (/tmp/debug.js:14:16)
    at o (/tmp/debug.js:15:16)
    at p (/tmp/debug.js:16:16)
    at q (/tmp/debug.js:17:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/debug.js:20:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the https://github.com/tlrobinson/long-stack-traces module.

Comment: Let's hope Node.js eventually integrates this by default!

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [built-in debugger](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_v8_inspector_integration_for_node_js), which opens familiar Google Chrome's dev-tools debugger. It stops on any error and you can browse the whole stack. Just run:

```
$ node --inspect debug.js

Debugger listening on port 9229.
To start debugging, open the following URL in Chrome: chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_file/...
```