# Console.log truncates my stacktrace. How to get longer prints?

Tags: debugging, node.js

I'm using console.log to debug errors while I develop, but it cuts off my stack traces after a handful of lines.

Is it possible to have it not do that? 
Is there a better "print to stdout" that I should be using for longer chunks like stack traces?

**Edit**: Regarding a comment from Ryan Olds, the problem isn't that the stack only includes the most recent "event', but that the string being printed by console.log is truncating after a certain number of characters. It often stops in the middle of a line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697038/more-than-10-lines-in-a-node-js-stack-error

Comment: Is it possible the log function hasn't finished writing before the process is terminated?  Does it stop in the middle of a line and immediately return a command prompt?

Comment: Sometimes it stops in the middle then goes back to the command prompt. Funny thing is that almost all my exceptions should be getting caught by try/catch, but I must have missed something somewhere.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`console.error(...)` seems to print the full stack message.