# How do you set node flags for a npm run-script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

There is a Node.js flag that increases the length of stack traces:

```
--stack-trace-limit (number of stack frames to capture)
     type: int  default: 10
```

But I am running my command like this from a `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "unit-test": "jasmine"
  }
```

This is not an NPM flag, or a Jasmine flag either. It's a flag for the `node` command.

How do can I set `--stack-trace-limit` when I `npm run unit-test`?

Comment: Specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/65596883/3001761.

Comment: Ah, yes it does!